# What's the reason that I can not successfully create an URL by using a string from a function in swift?

Tags: swift, url

I am a newbie in IOS development and recently take one course online. For one fetchWeather(cityName: String) function, I am trying to create an URL by a string that has the name of a weather forecast website, my API key and the city name. However, I find that if I use the `cityName` from the function, the URL fails. The wired thing is if I do not use the argument value, but create a new local variable `city_name` in the function that has the same value with `cityName`, which is the argument value, the URL succeed. Here are my two test cases:

```swift
func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
        // The first case that use the argument of the function
        print("First test case: ")
        print(cityName)
        let weatherURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=2b5e3c1ae10223238e8bbf73b814e563&units=metric&q="
        let first_urlString = weatherURL+cityName
        guard let first_url = URL(string:first_urlString)  else{
            print("First_URL fails")
        
        // The second case that directly combine two strings
            print("\nSecond test case: ")
            let city_name = "London"
            let second_url_String = weatherURL + city_name
            guard let second_url = URL(string:second_url_String)  else{
                print("Second_URL fails")
                return
            }
            print("Second_URL succeed")
            
            print("\n"+first_urlString)
            print(second_url_String)
            print("The first string is equals to the second string: " + String(first_urlString==second_url_String))
            
            return
        }
        print("First_URL succeed")
        
        
    }
```

And here's the output:

```swift
First test case: 
London 
First_URL fails

Second test case: 
Second_URL succeed

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=2b5e3c1ae10223238e8bbf73b814e563&units=metric&q=London 
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=2b5e3c1ae10223238e8bbf73b814e563&units=metric&q=London
The first string is equals to the second string: false
```

Those two url_strings look exactly the same, so why they are different? I believe that the difference between those two url_strings is the problem that my first URL fails and the second one succeed.

Comment: Could you print "cityName" length? Is there an invisible character os space a the end? Side note, it's recommended to use `URLQueryItems` to construct your URL.

Comment: You should make sure that there are no spaces at the end of your cityName. From the output you posted it looks like there is an additional space there

Comment: I suggest use `URLComonents` for `URL` generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job actually cutting and pasting your exact output into your question. That's how I was able to diagnose this.

The `cityName` you're passing to `fetchWeather` has a [U+0020 SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) at the end.

```
00000000  4c 6f 6e 64 6f 6e 20                              |London |
00000007
```

The URL parser doesn't like that. Try this instead:

```
let first_urlString = weatherURL + cityName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```